# Line after headline (css)

Tags: css

How can I create a line like this? (Check comments for screenshot)

I already tried to make a new div after the h1, and then styled it with

```
     margin-left: 70px;
     border-top: solid 2px #ffffff;
     width: 46.4%;
     margin-top: -27px;
     position: absolute;
```

But then the line is not long enough...

How is the smartest way to make these lines? So they are the same lenght as the div, they are place in. AND without making the mobile website too wide?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ab7Xn.png
I have not enough points to post images in my questions:-(

Comment: Is this on a website? You could inspect the CSS to figure out how they did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :after pseudo element without adding any div like this

```
h2 {
  position: relative;
}

h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/IkIyoVi/1/)

Comment: I did what you just explained, but there is two problems with that:
http://screencast.com/t/ADTTnNcM1A

Comment: So you have 2 options: 1. set the width of the main container or the h2 element to be aligned with the end of the last t-shirt. 2. Set the margin of t-shirts boxes to be aligned to the width of the container.